# how to find PDF of $X+Y$

Tags: probability

> Suppose $X$ has probability density function $f$, and $Y$ is uniformly
> distributed on [0,1]. Supposing X and Y are independent, find the
> probability density of $X + Y$

$$ f_{X+Y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(s)f_Y(t-s)ds $$

We know $f_Y(t-s)=1$ for $0 \leq t-s \leq 1$ and 0 elsewhere.

How do I use this information to simplify the above integral? I feel like I need to change bounds so that $f_Y(t-s)$ disappears, but I'm not sure how. I believe I need to substitute $s$ for $-\infty$ and $s+1$ for $\infty$ because $0 \leq t-s \leq 1 \leftrightarrow s \leq t \leq s+1$

So $$ f_{X+Y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(s)f_Y(t-s)ds =  \int_{s}^{s+1} f(s)ds$$ is the answer.

(I'm quite shaky on this material; apologize if this is poorly put)

Comment: Not quite, you are integrating over $s$ and so the limit should be something depending on $t$ rather than $s$, can you see what it should be?

Comment: Oh, should the bounds be $t-1,t$? Also, I just leave the solution as the last integral I wrote above with those new bounds, right?

Comment: yeah I think that should be right

Comment: Also on a second thought, you could probably write the result as a difference of two cdf, like $F(t+1)-F(t)$ but nevertheless it should be ok either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we are fixing a value of $t$; $s$ is a dummy integration variable so you cannot substitute it with anything. We have (due to independence)
\begin{align}
f_{X+Y}(t)&=(f*f_Y)(t)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(s)f_Y(t-s)\,ds\\
&=\int_{\{s\in\Bbb{R}\,:\, 0\leq t-s\leq 1\}}f(s)\cdot 1\,ds
\end{align}
The last equality is precisely for the reason you mentioned.

So, we're integrating over a certain set of $s$ values. This set depends on $t$, so you just have to rearrange the inequality "to make $s$ the subject of the inequality". For example, I'm sure you can verify that
\begin{align}
\{s\in\Bbb{R}\,:\, 0\leq 3-s\leq 1\}&= \{s\in\Bbb{R}\,:\, -1\leq s-3\leq 0\}\\
&=\{s\in\Bbb{R}\,:\, 2\leq s\leq 3\}\\
&=[2,3]
\end{align}
So, what is the result for a general value of $t$?

Comment: Ah, I believe it's $t-1$ to $t$?

Comment: @beginner yes exactly. Note that you were correct that $0\leq t-s\leq1 \iff s\leq t\leq s+1$. It's just that this isn't the most useful way of presenting the inequality. Saying $t-1\leq s\leq t$ is more useful because it makes it obvious where the integration bounds are.

Comment: ah, thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

there are several way to solve  your problem. One of these ways is to use the convolution but you must pay attention on the integral bounds.

To understand how convolution works in this case, observe that from $Z=X+Y$ you get

$$y=z-x$$

that is

$$0<z-x<1$$

now, when $0<z<1$ you must have that $0<x<z$ but when $z>1$ you have that $z-1<x<1$

Putting together these information, by integration you get

$$f_Z(z)=z\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;1)}(z)+(2-z)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[1;2]}(z)$$

that is a triangular density

In a more compact form,

$$f_Z(z)=[1-|1-z|]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;2]}(z)$$

---

A different way to understand the correct integral bounds when integrating in dx is to observe that the joint domain $(X,Z)$ is the following

[image]

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is also uniform $[0,1]$?

Comment: Also, in the plot, the $y$ axis should be $z.$ Correct me if I'm wrong.